# load cell continuously monitor load

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic, sensor, design, transducer

I want use 50 kg of load cell of weighing machine to measure 30 kg of load for an one or two months,and load continuously decreases because of consumption on daily basis. my question is that the weighing machine is continuously display accurate load or not? Is there chance of creep or fatigue ? no temperature phenomena acting on load cell, load show accurate result at every consumption?

Comment: If anything, the spec may hold the answer.

Comment: Maybe local gravity fluctuations?

Comment: Biggest question, what level of accuracy do you require? There may be fluctuations, but whether those are large enough to exceed your accuracy requirements, only you can say.

Answer (score 3):

Load cell creep is a problem, and generally is most pronounced early in the life of the cell as the adhesive or weld binding the element to the material under strain relaxes or moves.  This will vary depending on the bonding technique and the temperature cycling that the load cell experiences.  It is most prominent in the offset; the gain generally remains stable.  We have good luck "ageing in" load cell transducers at temperature to allow the bond to approach some type of equilibrium.  You generally will see the offset changes decrease over time.  You probably will want a tare feature to adjust for small changes that will occur over system life.

Comment: here temperature phenomena is negligible, no temperate acting on load cell.